# Rails 3 - Adding a partial to a nested form using javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

I've a nested forms partial in a Rails 3 application that looks like so:

```
<% f.fields_for :tips, tip do |tip_field| %>
  <p class="fields">
  Course: <%= tip_field.text_field :course %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Each email can have multiple tips. The multiple line entry works fine.
However, I want to be able to dynamically add new lines using Javascript. i.e. I want to be able to click "New Line", and have an extra child entry section added to the form.

The fields_for helper correctly creates the lines for entry. Each line looks something like:

```
  Course: <input id="email_tips_attributes_3_course" name="email[tips_attributes][3][course]" size="30" type="text" />
```

If I can pass the next line number, is there a helper like fields_for I can use that'll allow me to use this partial to dynamically return a new child entry section.

e.g. something like:

```
def newtip
  @tip = Tip.new
  f = imaginary_form_with_the_next_line_being(5)
  f.fields_for @tip do |ftip|
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :partial=>'tip_fields', :locals => {:tip => @tip, :f=>ftip}}
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following railscast. I think this is what you are looking for.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

The sample code is linked here: https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/tree/master/episode-197

Note, it is (well written) sample code. It depends on HTML tables. It was straight-forward to adapt it for use with jquery remote forms and hidden inputs, so you should be able to do the same for whatever structure your forms take.

Comment: This is a good resource. There is more code from Ryan on this subject here: https://github.com/ryanb/complex-form-examples

Comment: Thanks. I'd seen this, but couldn't make it work. I assumed that each new formset would be downloaded from the server as needed. Turns out, you can pop the text to be appended into the link as a parameter for the javascript function.